# Trying to extract data from MySQL to Excel using VBA

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am getting an error and I don't understand what is the problem. Here is my code

```
Sub test()
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlstr As String ' SQL to perform various actions
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection

    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=ETS-DEV-01;" & _
        "DATABASE=reporting;" & _
        "USER=guest_user;" & _
        "PASSWORD=0X4ZT9kwsY%yGOp;" & _
        "Option=3"
    sqlstr = "select * from tveuptimes"
    rs.Open sqlstr, oConn

End Sub
```

I am getting the error:
Run-time error '91'
Object variable or with block variable not set.

I don't understand what i am doing wrong.

Comment: missing single quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection` isn't necessary. Instead, when you dimension `rs` and `oConn` add the word `New` before the type, like this:

```
Sub test()
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlstr As String
Dim oConn As New ADODB.Connection

    oConn.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
        "SERVER=ETS-DEV-01;" & _
        "DATABASE=reporting;" & _
        "USER=guest_user;" & _
        "PASSWORD=0X4ZT9kwsY%yGOp;" & _
        "Option=3"
    sqlstr = "select * from tveuptimes"
    rs.Open sqlstr, oConn

End Sub
```

Here's a good tutorial: http://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/ado-sql-macros-connecting-database/